# Should each font character have it's own kern table?

Tags: fonts, kerning

I am designing a file format for storing fonts, it will be used in my game where i need to draw ASCII text on the screen. At first i thought that i needed to keep a separate kern table for every character in the font, but after researching i found out that many font file formats used in games don't have any kern tables at all (e.g., Arma's FXY font https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/FXY_File_Format), they just use one offset for each character to determine where to draw the next character. Is this enough for simple ASCII text?Are there any drawbacks/limitations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Simple ASCII text" has nothing to do with kerning. Some of the (potentially) most ugly kerning candidates *are* in the Simple ASCII range; even with all-caps text only you can expect "AV" and "TA" combos.

Whether or not to include kerning in your text engine depends on some factors not mentioned in your post:

1. The type of font. A square-ish font doesn't need accurate kerning as much as a fully antialiased high quality font. A font that mimicks an 8x8 monospaced system font does not need kerning; a font with an eccentric design (say, a very wide "T") may.
2. The size of the font in pixels. For an 8x8 pixel font I would simply not bother.
3. The overhead in calculating string widths and drawing text onto the screen. For a typical game, such as a shoot-em-up, drawing text is secondary only and should happen as fast as possible. For lots of text in an adventure-style game, you'd want nicer output.

Even the act of only *having to check* every combination for *possible* kerning is time consuming, whether or not it results in an adjustment. For fastest performance, you can have a list of adjustment values for every character **per character** -- essentially, for 96 characters you need 96 * 96 lookups. Any other algorithm is possible (e.g., a linked list per character) but will be slower -- and can use less memory.

Also, not *every* possible character combo needs kerning information. You should design your font with built-in white space left and right, the so-called "side bearing". This 'natural' spacing would only need adjustment for as little as possible combinations.

All in all, It Depends. Best is to try both: without and with kerning. Estimate the negative impact on the performance against the positive of the "looks", and decide which one you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, i guess i will use monospaced fonts only. I wanted to draw some scene statistics on the screen so i don't really care if the text looks "pretty".